# Why does my momentjs issameorafter() not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

In my VueJS application I'm using momentjs to validate if the user selected date is today or a future date.

Following is my custom validation rule.

```
const dateIsToday = (value) => {
    let todayDate = moment();
    let selectedDate = moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    return moment(selectedDate).isSameOrAfter(todayDate);
};
```

This rule works with older dates.

**But even when user selects a today's date, it gives an error.**

Instead I should be able to allow to select today's date.

Comment: can you also provide the date for which the error is happening? It will be helpful to answer your problem

Comment: "it gives an error" - what error?

Comment: @EstusFlask it show's the validation message for the current date as well

Comment: You are not getting the expected result because momentjs takes into account full date + time when comparing, as it's explained in the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/) and in several SO answers. You can simply add an extra parameter to limit granularity.